# Why is viewport meta tag needed on Android for this code?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

**Update 2 - 18-03-2017:** Apparently I need to use `window.devicePixelRatio`. I don't know exactly how yet. But that's what I need to figure out now.

I'm trying to divide a CSS-size of `300px` (each colored block has that height set) by `window.devicePixelRatio` but still my calculations are off it seems.

**Update 1 - 18-03-2017:** I think I've somewhat pinpointed the issue:

The maximum `scrollTop` value is far lower using e.g. Chrome for Android than it is using just Chrome (for desktops). Problem must lie in the `paddingTop` of `#scrolldistract`. I need to fill that empty `div` in such a way that this height or padding registers with Chrome for Android in that it increases the maximum `scrollTop` value. Now it just stays at around 540 no matter if I use `min-height` or `line-height` or a `table` with a certain amount of pixel height, etc.

---

In my code I'm trying to get some heights and coordinates dynamically. If I use the viewport meta tag as specified in the HTML code comment everything works on Chrome for Android and on Firefox for Android, just as it works using e.g. Chrome (desktop).

But when I don't insert a viewport meta tag it has the wrong measurements (on Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android) even though I'm requesting them dynamically.

I know there's such a thing as virtual pixels on mobile devices: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

But I do not understand exactly why the browser does not return the proper values (the practical values which I need to use). I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong here?

Why **not** use a viewport meta tag? Because I want to enable double tap - which is apparently very naughty of me because of a 300 ms delay. I really want to use double tap though because of the need to zoom some text (which is in visual form).

Well, there is of course the pinch-to-zoom gesture, which is still enabled with viewport meta tag (and which also appears to have some issues with or without viewport meta tag). But two taps is somewhat of a better suit for this purpose.

```js
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);
// Element which needs to fade in and out.
var $fadingblack = $("#fadingblack");
var $scrolldistract = $("#scrolldistract");
var $scrollsviascrolldistract = $("#scrollsviascrolldistract");
// Pulls up the child divs of #scrollsviascrolldistract, under it.
var $puller = $("#puller");


// Start of fading area (Y-value).
var scrollTopStart = $fadingblack.position().top;
// And of course the Y-value of the end of the fading area.
var scrollTopEnd = scrollTopStart + $fadingblack.height();

// Maximum scrollTop-value (when scrollbar is at 100%).
var lastScrollTop = $document.height() - $window.height();

// Amount of scrolled pixels (vertically) including amount scrolled while
// the fading element is fading.
var scrollAmountWithFadeAmount = $document.height + $fadingblack.height();
// Setting height does not quite work for an empty div,
// so we are using some padding.
$scrolldistract.css("paddingTop", scrollAmountWithFadeAmount);
// Percentage of which we have scrolled (1 = 100%).
var currentScrollTopP;
// Current scrollTop value.
var realCurY;

$(function() {
  // Off you go code...

  function doScrollOrFade() {
    currentScrollTopP = Math.ceil($window.scrollTop() / lastScrollTop * 100) / 100;
    realCurY = currentScrollTopP * lastScrollTop;

    if (realCurY >= scrollTopStart && realCurY <= scrollTopEnd) {
      // Current realCurY dictates we are in fade area.
      // So scroll the fading area into view at top of browser viewport.
      $puller.css("marginTop", -scrollTopStart);
      // Determine opacity percentage.
      var fadePercent = (realCurY - scrollTopStart) / (scrollTopEnd - scrollTopStart);
      // Fade to current opacity immediately.
      $fadingblack.fadeTo(0, fadePercent);
    } else {
      // We are outside of the fading area and in scroll-mode.
      if (realCurY < scrollTopStart) {
        // We are somewhere before the fading area, so set opacity to 0.
        $fadingblack.fadeTo(0, 0);
      } else {
        // We are somewhere after the fading area, so set opacity to 1.
        $fadingblack.fadeTo(0, 1);
      }

      if (realCurY > scrollTopEnd) {
        // We have passed the fading area. So we have an amount
        // of pixels we wasted on the opacity changes.
        // Correct it here.
        $puller.css("marginTop", -realCurY + $fadingblack.height());
      } else {
        $puller.css("marginTop", -realCurY);
      }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doScrollOrFade);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(doScrollOrFade);

  $window.on('resize orientationchange', function(e) {
    // On resize or orientation change recalculate some stuff.
    lastScrollTop = $document.height() - $window.height();
    scrollAmountWithFadeAmount = $document.height + $fadingblack.height();
    $scrolldistract.css("paddingTop", scrollAmountWithFadeAmount);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doScrollOrFade);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#scrollsviascrolldistract {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#scrolldistract {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2100px;
  height: 0px;
}

#puller {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.black,
.red,
.blue {
  border: solid 1px yellow;
  font-size: 32pt;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!--
For mobile support use viewport meta-tag inside <head>:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrolldistract"></div>

<div id="scrollsviascrolldistract">
  <!-- For pulling up the red, blue and fading area -->
  <div id="puller"></div>
  <div class="red">BEGIN</div>
  <div class="blue">Fading black area is ahead...</div>
  <div id="fadingblack" class="black">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">END</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewport meta tag is used to scale the page to the size of the device physical height and width of the display; without it the browser load the page and shrink it down so it fit the screen. Therefore in theory the height and width of a page without viewport is same as the desktop